# Use file system Oak repository

Tags: filesystems, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I have migrated Apache Jackrabbit file repository to Oak using oak-upgrade utility in order to replace the jackrabbit with Oak. How can I use the new oak repository ? The `segmentstore` folder contains below files

```
data00000a.tar
journal.log 
manifest
```

How to connect to this new repository using Oak classes ? I tried below

```
Repository repo = JcrUtils.getRepository("file://d:\\testing\\oak\\segmentstore");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would work-

```
FileStore fs = FileStoreBuilder.fileStoreBuilder(new File("d:\\testing\\oak")).build();
SegmentNodeStore ns = SegmentNodeStoreBuilders.builder(fs).build();
Repository repo = new Jcr(new Oak(ns)).createRepository();
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked. The path should contain the .tar file.